Can you skip blank rows in a XMATCH lookup so #N/A is not returned?
I have an Excel workbook where I am extracting totals from monthly worksheets to a master sheet. I use the INDEX + XMATCH method as per the formula below:
    =IFERROR(INDEX(Jul2024Totals,XMATCH(ConsolCodes,Jul2024Codes,0)), "$0.00")

where I XMATCH the master worksheet codes in a column range I have named ConsolCodes with the monthly codes, in another column I have named July2024Codes, where I return the INDEXed totals from July2024Totals.  This works fine except where there are blank cells in each of the MATCHED code named ranges. Sure, I can do error trapping to return a NULL value but this only applies to non-matched values and not BLANK cell values. Is there some way to avoid this, like perhaps an IF statement wrapping around the formula, which I have tried but still get a return of #N/A. So either this is not possible or maybe there is some other method?

By checking blanks in ConsolCodes first:
=IF(ISBLANK(ConsolCodes),0, IFERROR(INDEX(Jul2024Totals,XMATCH(ConsolCodes,Jul2024Codes,0)), 0))



Although FILTER option works with ISNUMBER your option with ISBLANK, adjusted to return a NULL ("") value, gives me the result I was looking for.

You could try using the FILTER() function and ISNUMBER() or 1-ISNA() to avoid the errors :
=FILTER(Jul2024Totals,1-ISNA(XMATCH(Jul2024Codes,ConsolCodes)),"")


Or, alternatively using ISNUMBER() instead of 1-ISNA()
=FILTER(Jul2024Totals,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Jul2024Codes,ConsolCodes)),"")


The above formula will return a single array output.
